# How to change only one passing variable in onClick event Jquery

Tags: jquery, function, variables, onclick

I have onClick event and I´d like to change only one of passed variables :

```
onClick="fce('<?php echo $sql_2_vypis["technologie_typ_text"] ?>','<?php echo $sql_2_vypis["technologie_typ_ID"] ?>','<?php echo $bunka ?>')"
```

and I like to change only third value and the first and second must stay the same.

If I use `.attr('onclick','fce(...)')` It change whole event...

Please try to help. Thank you. Tomas

Answer (score 0):

If you are using inline javascript you can use this

```
<script>
    var typText = '<?php echo $sql_2_vypis["technologie_typ_text"] ?>';
    var typId = '<?php echo $sql_2_vypis["technologie_typ_ID"] ?>';
    function fce(bunka) {
        // here you have all the 3 variables available
    }
</script>
```

If your function is defined in external javascript file

php file

```
<header>
 <script src="app.js"></script>
 <script>
        config.typText = '<?php echo $sql_2_vypis["technologie_typ_text"] ?>';
        config.typId = '<?php echo $sql_2_vypis["technologie_typ_ID"] ?>';
  </script>
</header>
```

javascript file (app.js)

```
var config = {
    typId: undefined,
    typTxt: undefined
}

function fce(bunka) {
   // three variables are available
   // config.typId
   // config.typTxt
}
```